# Генерация документов Open XML, с чего начать?

Tags: asp.net, xml

Необходимо генерировать документы Word, используя функции вставки картинок, их группировка, всевозможное форматирование текста, работа с колонтитулами и т.д. Буду рад ссылкам на исчерпывающий материал.

Comment: Есть плагин к Visual Studio: [Open XML Package Editor Power Tool for Visual Studio 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/450a00e3-5a7d-4776-be2c-8aa8cec2a75b) Позволяет удобно просматривать и изменять внутренние xml'ки файлов docx.

Comment: Вот еще нашел библиотеку [`DocX`](http://docx.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала стоит ознакомиться [Open XML SDK 2.0 для Microsoft Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb448854.aspx), затем стоит посмотреть [System.IO.Packaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.packaging.aspx). В принципе, OpenXML - это просто zip-архив, где есть XML-метаданные и XML-данные.